# AngularJs calling multiple service function : which is the best way to call multiple REST service on angularjs during the init step?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this infrastructure

**[play] <-REST-> [karaf]**

and this controller

```
        $scope.getPrototypes = function (node) {
            connectHttpService.getPrototypes(function (response) {

                $scope.prototypes = response;
            }, node);
        }

        $scope.getCommandsWithAck = function (node) {

            connectHttpService.getCommands(function (response) {

                $scope.commandsWithAck = response;

            },  node, true);
        }

        $scope.getCommandsWithoutAck = function (node) {

            connectHttpService.getCommands(function (response) {

                $scope.commandsWithoutAck = response;
            },  node, false);
        }
```

where `connectHttpService` is the service

```
    function getCommands(successHandler, failHandler, nodeId, ack) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
                       ........MY ENDPOINT.........

            }
        }).success(function(response) {
            successHandler(response);
        }).error(function(response) {
            console.log("connectHttpService got an error response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
        })
    }
```

**the problem** is my init method (called thorugh `ng-init`) is

```
      $scope.initCommands = function () {

                $scope.currentNode = $stateParams.node;
                $scope.getPrototypes($scope.currentNode); //(1)
                $scope.getCommandsWithAck($scope.currentNode); //(2)
                $scope.getCommandsWithoutAck($scope.currentNode); //(3)
            }
        }
```

the `$scope.getCommandsWithoutAck` is called but doesn't return. On the server side (karaf) I see the call and the response. No error on the browser.

- if I remove (1) or (2) it works
- if I change the position of (3) and (2) it works, but only since (2) doesn't return nothing.

In other words: **which is the best way to call multiple REST service on angularjs during the init step?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use [**$q**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Like this

```
$scope.currentNode = $stateParams.node;
$q.all([

    $scope.getPrototypes($scope.currentNode), //(1)
    $scope.getCommandsWithAck($scope.currentNode), //(2)
    $scope.getCommandsWithoutAck($scope.currentNode) //(3)

]).then(function(result){

   console.log(result[0]);//(1)
   console.log(result[1]);//(2)
   console.log(result[2]);//(3)

});
```

And you have to return promise from service

Like this

```
$scope.getCommandsWithAck = function (node) {

         return   connectHttpService.getCommands(function (response) {

                $scope.commandsWithAck = response.data;
                return $scope.commandsWithAck; //to complete promise
            },  node, true);
        }
```

**N:B**: you have to inject $q in your controller